# Format text string in matlab

Tags: string, matlab, scanf

I'm trying to only extract a parameter name from a string I have:

```
vi('$Excitation', '0A', '0A', '0A')
```

I only want the "$Excitation" out of it.

Currently I'm using:

```
for a = 1:length(Parameters);
    Par{a,1} = sscanf ((Parameters{a,1}),'vi(''%s, %*s, %*s, %*s,%*s')';
    titles{1,a} = Par{a,1};
end
```

Which gets me:

```
"$Excitation',"
```

I've tried changing to :

```
'vi(''%s'',, %*s, %*s, %*s,%*s'
```

And get no change in result.

Any suggestions? Also helpful to explain why what I have doesn't work, so I don't make the same mistake again!

**Edit:**

I also have a similar problem for "gi('MagFlux(Current1): Matrix1', 19, 131, 'Wb')" Where I'd like "MagFlux_Wb" as an output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does work is this:

```
OP=textscan((Parameters{a,1}),'%s','whitespace','','delimiter',' ''(),','multipledelimsasone',true);
Par{a,1} = OP{2};
titles{1,a} = Par{a,1};
```

As for why your original code didn't work, it's because sscanf reads %s until whitespace:

Your string is:

```
vi('$Excitation', '0A', '0A', '0A')
```

Putting `vi(` at the start of your formatstring means it gets ignored, so the '%s' is searching through this:

```
'$Excitation', '0A', '0A', '0A')
```

It reads until it hits whitespace: `'$Excitation',` and so this matches your first `%s`. 
The comma you are inserted into the formatstring is ignored until the %s is first dealt with, which is why it didn't do what you expected.

What remains is then

```
'0A', '0A', '0A')
```

Which doesn't really match the rest of your formatstring: `, %*s, %*s, %*s,%*s')` so the output isn't as expected.

What I did was use textscan which allows you to specify what delimiters or whitespace you want to use to split strings. So I stopped it splitting strings with spaces by telling it to use no whitespace, and instead told it to use `space`, `'`, `left and right brackets`, and `comma` as delimiters to split the sentence up, and if there are two or more delimiters in a row, count them as a single break (otherwise you get empty cell elements).

Comment: Thank you very much! Very useful answer. Always nice to have things explained  well.